# generator QR code scanner by passing link in image tag

Tags: html, image, qr-code, image-scanner

**I need to generate a QR code Scanner by passing a link url.**
Trying to do with googleAPIS but its deprecated (services are stopped in 2019).
**Is there any other way to do? any other API is there to work like googleApis?**
one more API(qr code Api) i have tried but didn't work.
am sharing some link with reference to this api.

```
 <img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chl=Hello+World&chs=160x160&chld=L|0"
         class="qr-code img-thumbnail img-responsive">
```

http://goqr.me/api/doc/create-qr-code/(create qr code API)

https://codepen.io/MathewSachin/pen/LxPzob(with reference to run)

https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes(Google APIS)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

goqr.me API is working fine.

Have you passed the URL as an encoded form?
Please pass URL in an encoded form.

```
<img src="https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com&size=300x300">
```

You can try this one also https://qrickit.com/qrickit_apps/qrickit_api.php

```
<img src="https://qrickit.com/api/qr.php?d=http://google.com&addtext=Hello+World&txtcolor=442EFF&fgdcolor=76103C
&bgdcolor=C0F912&qrsize=510&t=p&e=m">
```

Comment: Thank u so much, goqr.me is working for me. 
i didn't pass url as an encoded form.
but not getting amount on gPay screen.

Comment: how can i pass the URL as base64 encoded form in qrcode(goqr.me)?